PySpark error when "from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler"
I am getting error when trying this in Jupyter:
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
featureassembler=VectorAssembler(inputCols=["age","Experience"],outputCol="Independent Features")

Error:
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 1
----> 1 from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
      2 featureassembler=VectorAssembler(inputCols=["age","Experience"],outputCol="Independent Features")

File ~/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/pyspark/ml/__init__.py:22
      1 #
      2 # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
      3 # contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
   (...)
     15 # limitations under the License.

I have already downloaded a license from http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 into my working directory.
